# Virtualization frameworks and containers effectiveness on hardware without iommu capability?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, container, qubes, iommu

Is it worth installing VirtualBox with a Linux based distributed OS like Kali or Qubes if your hardware does not support iommu? Is there any benefit in regards to security if isolation is limited?

Answer (score 1):

Yes; iommu is only helpful if you need to physically allocate e.g. a PCIe device to the VM. Usually, you don't do that.

Kali is not a general-purpose OS, https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/ , and you probably should not be using it as virtualization host. Please read that document carefully, since your username contains "Noob", Kali is really the wrong choice: it doesn't even try to be useful to you.

I don't know what you mean with "if isolation is limited"; unless you have a VM escape that the world is not aware of, Linux-based VMs are pretty well-isolated. If you mean containers, that discussion is a little over-done by now and should probably be researched with your specific use case in mind. But seeing the ubiquity of containers in server environments to isolate individual services, cursory consideration should offer you some insight.